# Is there any way to use extension fields in docker-compose with docker secrets?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, devops, docker-swarm

Let's imagine that we have docker stack which is configured by .yml file with 3 services - a,b and c. Also, there are a bunch of secrets that these services use. Two for the database, Azure service and some unique for each service. So, our .yml file looks like:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
 a:
  image: a-image
  [...]
  secrets:
   -db.pwd
   -db.user
   -azure.secret_key
   -azure.public_key
   -a.secret_key1
   -a.secret_key2
 b:
  image: b-image
  [...]
  secrets:
   -db.pwd
   -db.user
   -b.secret_key1
   -b.secret_key2
 c:
  image: c-image
  [...]
  secrets:
   -db.pwd
   -db.user
   -azure.secret_key
   -azure.public_key
   -c.secret_key1
   -c.secret_key2

secrets:
 db.pwd:
  external: true
 db.user:
  external: true
 azure.secret_key:
  external: true
 azure.public_key:
  external: true
 a.secret_key1:
  external: true
 a.secret_key2:
  external: true
 b.secret_key1:
  external: true
 b.secret_key2:
  external: true
 c.secret_key1:
  external: true
 c.secret_key2:
  external: true
```

As you can see some secrets are repeated in each service.
docker-compose file has such thing as "Extension fields" - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields
Is there any way how I can use this extension fields to avoid repeating of secrets?
Something like this:

```
version: '3.4'
x-common-db-secrets: &db-secrets
 - db.user
 - db.pwd

x-common-azure-secrets: &azure-secrets
 - azure.public_key
 - azure.secret_key

services:
 a:
  image: a-image
  [...]
  secrets:
   <<: *db-secrets
   <<: *azure-secrets
   -a.secret_key1
   -a.secret_key2
 b:
  image: b-image
  [...]
  secrets:
   <<: *db-secrets
   -b.secret_key1
   -b.secret_key2
 c:
  image: c-image
  [...]
  secrets:
   <<: *db-secrets
   <<: *azure-secrets
   -c.secret_key1
   -c.secret_key2

secrets:
 [...]
```

I am using this extension fields for such way of sharing environment variables. But the structure required for parsing extension fields is map. And “secrets” section requires list. Have anyone ideas how to deal with it right?Please note that in future there can be added new secrets that will be used in old and new services for example, so the solution has to be flexible. I will be really appreciated to find an answer. Am searching an answer for any compose version 3.4+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to use YAML anchors and aliases to combine list items into a single flat list. However, docker-compose has its own deep-merging process for Compose files, which you could combine with YAML anchors and aliases to get the effect you're looking for. You'll need to split your service definitions into two files for this. Here's an example

#### foo.yml

This Compose file has an extension named `x-secrets` that declares secrets named `one` and `two`. It has an anchor named `secrets`, and it's used it to fill in the common secrets for services `a` and `b`.

```
version: "3.7"

x-secrets: &secrets
  secrets:
    - one
    - two

services:
  a:
    <<: *secrets
    image: a-image

  b:
    <<: *secrets
    image: b-image

secrets:
  one:
    external: true
  two:
    external: true
```

#### bar.yml

Next, this Compose file extends the service `a` with two extra secrets, named `three` and `four`.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  a:
    secrets:
      - three
      - four

secrets:
  three:
    external: true
  four:
    external: true
```

#### Combining Compose Files

With the two files in place, tell docker-compose to use them both for the project configuration. The files will be merged—in order—to form one complete config. I'm using the `config` command to show the final config.

```
$ docker-compose -f foo.yml -f bar.yml config
secrets:
  four:
    external: true
    name: four
  one:
    external: true
    name: one
  three:
    external: true
    name: three
  two:
    external: true
    name: two
services:
  a:
    image: a-image
    secrets:
    - source: four
    - source: one
    - source: three
    - source: two
  b:
    image: b-image
    secrets:
    - source: one
    - source: two
version: '3.7'
```

Here, you can see that service `a` now has four secrets. The lists of secrets from `foo.yml` and `bar.yml` have been merged together.

As an aside, you can specify the list of Compose files using an environment variable named `COMPOSE_FILE`, which can also be placed in a file named [`.env`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/).

Comment: Combining Compose Files - seems not a right way for solving such problem, because in case of growing new secrets amount of files for combining will be growing.

Comment: I actually recommend using multiple Compose files for a variety of use cases. In your case, you shouldn't need more than two. Have all your common configurations in one (foo.yml), and all the extras for all the services in the other (bar.yml). Unfortunately, using just YAML anchors and aliases isn't sufficient for lists.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not my use case, it is an example. Because I have 15+ different services that has common and unique secrets. In this case multiple files make it more complex. Even the duplication of code like described in my first example sounds better, as for me. Anyway, thank you for your answer.